# I have an option tag defined under datalist, I have passed value and label to option tag, but its showing both Label + Value in dropdown

Tags: html, html-select, svelte

[image]

Even after passing label attribute its showing both label and value in dropdown also, after selecting option from dropdown its showing value in input box insteed of label

[image]

```
<input
  on:change={onChangeSuggestion}
  on:input={updateValue}
  list="inventoryLocations"
  id="store-locator-mapbox-input"
  placeholder="Search store or address..."
  type="text"
/>
<datalist id="inventoryLocations">
  {#each suggestions as location}
    <option value={[location.geometry.coordinates[0], location.geometry.coordinates[1]]} label={location.place_name} />
  {/each}
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How `datalist` options are presented depends on the browser, e.g. Firefox will not show the `value` in the list. The only constant is that the `value` will be what will end up in the `input` because inputs of type `text` have no hidden value (unlike `select`).

If you need more control over the appearance, the only real option is using a custom component that renders its own input/dropdown without relying on `datalist`. There are libraries which provide this functionality with varying features and accessibility.